# How many books are in a library?

Tags: probability, statistics

My cousin is at elementary school and every week is given a book by his teacher.  He then reads it and returns it in time to get another one the next week. After a while we started noticing that he was getting books he had read before and this became gradually more common over time.   Naturally, I started to wonder how one could estimate the total number of books in their library.

Say the true number of books in the library is $N$ and the teacher picks one uniformly at random (with replacement) to give to you each week.  If at week $t$ you have received a book you have read before $x$ times, is there an unbiased estimator for the total number of books in the library and what is the variance of this estimator? Is there another biased estimator with lower variance?

In my cousin's case, in the first $30$ weeks he received a book he had received before $3$ times.

Comment: Is "in first 30 weeks he received a book he had received before 3 times" talking about the worst example, or about what happened on the 30th week?

Comment: This is a variant of the Birthday problem, where instead of knowing the number of days in a year and estimating when you get your first collision, you look at how many collisions you get and estimate the total number of "days in a year" (books in the library). There are ways of doing this, but I haven't had any real statistics, so I don't know them too well. @Henry I assume it means that for 3 of the 30 weeks he didn't have anything interesting to read, since he got a book he had already read.

Comment: @Henry I meant that over the course of the first 30 weeks, on three occasions he was given a book that he had been given in some previous week (as Arthur also said).  Can you improve the estimate if you also know on exactly which of the first 30 weeks he was given these duplicate books? It would make sense that knowing the date of the most recent duplicate book would tell you something.

Comment: @Anush: why do you think the timing affects anything?  I suspect that the number of weeks and the number of originals would be a sufficient statistic on the assumption that books are random

Comment: @Henry In all honesty I don't know. Getting 3 duplicates in the first 4 weeks and then none for 26 weeks might give the same as 3 duplicates evenly spread out over 30 weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given there are $N$ books in total and $t$ weeks, the probability of having received $x$ duplicates (i.e. $t-x$ unique books) is $$S_2(t,t-x) \frac{ N!}{(N-(t-x))! N^t}$$ where $S_2$ denotes a Stirling number of the second kind.  In your example $S_2(30,27)=10359090$.

The maximum likelihood estimate of $N$ given $t=30$ and $x=3$ is $135$.  If there really were $N=135$ books then the expected number of duplicates would be about $3.01017$, while if there were $N=136$ books then the expected number of duplicates would be about $2.98951$. The value for $N$ which would give exactly $3$ is about $135.4907$ though of course this is not an integer.

So $135$ is a reasonable estimate.  But there is still considerable uncertainty: any value for $N$ from $56$ to $601$ would have a likelihood for $3$ duplicates out of $30$ more than a tenth of the likelihood resulting from $N=135$. The variance for the number of duplicates if $N=135$ is about $2.26258$.

Comment: Thank you. How do you compute the standard error (or variance) for this maximum likelihood estimate?

Comment: Assuming there are at least 30 books, there will be a positive probability of no duplicates in 30 weeks, with an unbounded maximum likelihood estimate.  So what do you mean by *"the standard error (or variance)"* ?

Comment: I may have got things confused but in your answer you give a maximum likelihood estimate of $135$.  I was asking about the standard error for this estimator (see for example http://www.unc.edu/courses/2010fall/ecol/563/001/docs/lectures/lecture8.htm point 4.).

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you are thinking about, but I am suggesting that, for any actual number of books of 30 or more, there is is a positive probability that there will be no duplicates and so there is is a positive probability that the maximum likelihood estimator will be infinite, and so there is is a positive probability that the error will be infinite. So the standard error of the maximum likelihood estimator will also be infinite....

Comment: ... This is of course not what you want.  You know in this case that the maximum liklihood estimate (not *estimator*) is finite.  One way round this would be to use Bayesian methods, assuming a prior for the number of books and using the fact of three duplicates to produce a posterior distribution, and then finding the standard deviation of that posterior distribution.  But I do not think that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks again.  How did you compute the variance for the number of duplicates if $N=135$?  I am generally trying to understand how one's confidence in this MLE varies as a function of the number of weeks and the number of duplicates. Intuitively it seems that if you have 29 duplicates in 30 weeks then you are pretty sure there is only one book. But if you had no duplicates then should have some confidence there are at least $x$ books. But I don't know how to quantify this.

Comment: If there are $N=135$ and 30 weeks, the probability of 0 duplicates is about: $0.0306$, of 1 duplicate about: $0.1256$, 2: $0.2328$, 3: $0.2588$, 4: $0.1933$, 5: $0.1030$, 6: $0.0405$, 7: $0.0120$, 8: $0.0027$, 9: $0.0005$, etc.  This can be usesd to calculate the expected number of duplicates and the variance.

Comment: In the end I realised that all I wanted was a formula for a 95% confidence interval as a function of the number of weeks and the number of duplicates seen! Sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 7):

The [Good-Turing estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good%E2%80%93Turing_frequency_estimation) is given by $$\hat M ={N \over {1-{N_1 \over K}}}$$ where $N$ is the number of different names observed, $N_1$ is the number of names seen once, and $K$ is the total number of observations. For your data, assuming 24 observations were unique and the 3 duplicates were all seen twice, this yields $$\hat M = {27 \over {1-{24 \over 30}}}= 135.$$ I don't know about the standard error of this estimate; look up Good-Turing and see what you can find.

Answer (score 4):

The book picked on week $t$ was never picked before if, independently and $t-1$ times, another book was picked. This happens with probability $p^{t-1}$, where $p=1-N^{-1}$. Thus, the mean number of weeks up to week $t$ when the book picked was not a new one is
$$
W_t=\sum_{s=1}^t\left(1-p^{s-1}\right)=t-\frac{1-p^t}{1-p},
$$
that is,
$$
t-W_t=N\cdot(1-(1-N^{-1})^t).\tag{$\ast$}
$$
The RHS increases from $1$ when $N=1$ to $t$ when $N=\infty$ and the book picked on week $1$ is always a new one, hence $0\leqslant W_t\leqslant t-1$. For every observed $W_t$ in $\{0,1,\ldots,0,t-1\}$, there exists a unique $\hat N_t$ such that $(\ast)$ holds.

The exact value of $\hat N_t$ has no algebraic expression when $t$ is large but, in the limit $t\to\infty$ and $W_t/t\to\mathtt w$, one knows that $\hat N_t/t$ converges to the unique solution $\nu$ of the equation
$$
\nu\cdot(1-\mathrm e^{-1/\nu})=1-\mathtt w.\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Numerically, if $t=30$ and $W_t=3$, $(\ast)$ yields $\hat N_t=135.49$ hence one would conclude that $N=135$ or $N=136$, and the approximation $(\dagger)$ with $\mathtt w=1/10$ yields $\nu t=139.8$, which is not too far off the mark even though $t=30$ is relatively small (note that $\nu t$ always overestimates $\hat N_t$, due to convexity).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to compute the standard error for this estimator? Also, is it in fact sufficent just to count how many books have been duplicated after 30 weeks or could it help to know exactly when the duplicates occurred?