# I pull $17$ balls out of a bag, and there are $13$ distinct colors in the sample. About how many colors are in the bag?

Tags: probability

I have a bag filled with different colors of balls.  My goal is to determine the number of distinct colors that in the bag, but I am limited to taking a small sample.  From a sample of $N$ balls, I see that there $X$ different colors.  What is the expected number of different colors in the bag?

Some assumptions which need to be made:

- The bag is of sufficiently large size that the probability of drawing a certain color does not depend on the how many balls we have already drawn.  (Effectively, we are drawing with replacement.)
- There is an equal number of each color in the bag.

For an example, let's say that I draw $N=17$ balls out of the bag, and I see $X=13$ distinct colors.  What is a good estimate for the number of colors in the bag?

So far, I have made little progress towards answering this on my own. I have tried to reverse the solution to the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) (as to solve for the number of colors as opposed to the number of trials), but I became stuck since it involved the harmonic numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on how many balls you have in the bag?

Comment: Would it be allowed to taking many small samples, or are we restricted to just the one?

Comment: @Marc I would prefer a solution with a single sample, if feasible.  What would be the difference between multiple small samples and one large sample?

Comment: @user88595 The size of the bag could serve as an upper bound (and thus change the estimate slightly), but I think that would only be important when the sample is a significant portion of the bag.  I made the simplifying assumption that the bag was large enough relative to the sample so that those effects would be negligible.

Comment: Similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615464/how-many-books-are-in-a-library/

Answer (score 3):

If the sample is size $n$, the likelihood you see $X=x$ different colours when there are $Y=y$ possible colours is proportional to $$\dfrac{y!}{(y-x)! y^n}.$$

So given $X=x$, the maximum likelihood estimate for $Y$ is the positive real solution to  $y(y-1)^n -(y-x) y^n=0$ rounded down, or in other words the largest integer $y$ for which the left hand-side is non-negative. (Note that if $x=n$ the maximum likelihood estimate is infinite.)

In this particular case with $n=17$ and $X=13$, the maximum likelihood estimate for $Y$ is $28$.

The uncertainty is considerable: any value for $Y$ from $15$ through to $91$ would have a likelihood for seeing $13$ unique colours from a sample of $17$ more than a tenth of the likelihood resulting from $Y=28$.