# Estimating the number of chips in a bag

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, confidence-interval

Suppose I have a bag containing an unknown number *N* of plastic chips.  The chips are labeled so that they are distinguishable; no two chips have the same label.

I draw a chip from the bag, observe its label, and put it back.  After I've done this some number of times, I would like to estimate *N*.

As an example, suppose I draw and replace 50 times.  41 distinct chips come up; 7 come up twice and one comes up three times.  What can I conclude about *N*?  Obviously *N≥41*, but also it is extremely unlikely that *N* is as large as 1000; if it were, we would expect far fewer duplicates.

This is very similar to the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem).  But there the crucial difference is that in the German tank problem the chips are labeled with consecutive numbers $1\ldots N$ and the labels themselves give us information about the population size.

Another very similar problem is the ecological problem of estimating a population size.  [Mark and recapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) is a simple and effective method, but it's not quite what I'm after here.  For mark-and-recapture we'd want to sample the chips twice, and compare the two samples.  If, say, the second half of the samples included 6 chips we saw from the first sample, we might guess that $N$ is around 100.

> Specifically, what I want is a method:
>
> - The input is a vector of how many chips appeared $k$ times for each $k$. In the example above the vector is $\langle 33, 7, 1, 0, 0, \ldots\rangle$.  We also have a probability $p$, say $p=0.95$ representing the degree of confidence we want to have in our answer.
> - The output is an interval $[ N_{\text{min}}, N_{\text{max}}]$ such that $N$ lies in this interval with probability close to $p$, and which also contains the $N$ that is most likely.

I am sure this has been studied extensively and I would be glad for a reference to the literature.

Comment: See the related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615464/how-many-books-are-in-a-library and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197635/guessing-number-of-colors-of-beads-in-an-urn and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760664/i-pull-17-balls-out-of-a-bag-and-there-are-13-distinct-colors-in-the-sample and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122699/how-to-estimate-the-number-of-articles-on-wikipedia-using-the-random-article-f

Comment: Thanks, I will close as duplicate once I look over the answers you pointed to and find the most satisfactory one.

Comment: I think you will find that the maximum likelihood estimate is $119$ for your particular example of $41$ unique chips form $50$ draws, but there are other methods too.  A confidence interval is harder but might range from under $75$ to over $230$, depending on how you do it.